# Mongoose error when loading model files from a parallel Mean.js project by using require

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have a Mean.js project, very basic as I'm just learning my way around this space. I created a parallel project in a seperate folder for a few tests, and I'm not using the mean.js framework for this as it's just command line stuff that I'm using to do some experimentation with.

When I try to include one of the mongoose model files from the mean.js project I run into problems. using the absolute or relative paths I can load the file(shown by some debug statements in the file that I add) but I cannot use the schema that should be registered once it has been included. If I copy the file to the local project folder and require that copy, it all works fine.

So, I'm trying to understand if there is some limitation on how require includes data from other folders.

Examples:

```
require('user.server.model.js'); //works
require('./user.server.model.js'); //works
require('./../../site/app/models/user.server.model.js'); //fails
require('../../site/app/models/user.server.model.js'); //fails
require('/home/mean/site/app/models/user.server.model.js'); //fails
```

The require succeeds, but when I later try to use the model registered in that file, I get errors on the ones that fail.

```
var User = mongoose.model('User'); //fails on the ones that requied the original location
//Error: MongooseError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "User".
```

I have tried other tools, like rekuire, but no success. Additionaly I have tried using a symlink and experienced the same failures. The files are identical according to diff and the fact that I directly copied the file. This project is not loading any of the express components, and that is fine. I have tried to follow the program flow on the express side of things and I see no reason that this should happen(especially when it works with a local copy).

I want to bring in my data models for mongoose from my main application, but not bring this code base into that app, anyone see a way to do this?

**Edit**

Shortened version of my code that is failing:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
require(path.resolve('./user.server.model.js'));
var User = mongoose.model('User'); //errors here if I use a require like the failing ones above
```

And the code in the boilerplate model file:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
        Schema = mongoose.Schema,
        crypto = require('crypto');

/**
 * A Validation function for local strategy properties
 */
var validateLocalStrategyProperty = function(property) {
        return ((this.provider !== 'local' && !this.updated) || property.length);
};

/**
 * A Validation function for local strategy password
 */
var validateLocalStrategyPassword = function(password) {
        return (this.provider !== 'local' || (password && password.length > 6));
};

/**
 * User Schema
 */
var UserSchema = new Schema({
        firstName: {
                type: String,
                trim: true,
                default: '',
                validate: [validateLocalStrategyProperty, 'Please fill in your first     name']
        },
        lastName: {
                type: String,
                trim: true,
                default: '',
                validate: [validateLocalStrategyProperty, 'Please fill in your last     name']
        },
        displayName: {
                type: String,
                trim: true
        },
        email: {
                type: String,
                trim: true,
                default: '',
                validate: [validateLocalStrategyProperty, 'Please fill in your email'],
                match: [/.+\@.+\..+/, 'Please fill a valid email address']
        },
        username: {
                type: String,
                unique: true,
                required: 'Please fill in a username',
                trim: true
        },
        password: {
                type: String,
                default: '',
                validate: [validateLocalStrategyPassword, 'Password should be longer']
        },
        salt: {
                type: String
        },
        provider: {
                type: String,
                required: 'Provider is required'
        },
        providerData: {},
        additionalProvidersData: {},
        roles: {
                type: [{
                        type: String,
                        enum: ['user', 'admin']
                }],
                default: ['user']
        },
        updated: {
                type: Date
        },
        created: {
                type: Date,
                default: Date.now
        }
});

/**
 * Hook a pre save method to hash the password
 */
UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
        if (this.password && this.password.length > 6) {
                this.salt = new Buffer(crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('base64'),     'base64');
                this.password = this.hashPassword(this.password);
        }

        next();
});

/**
 * Create instance method for hashing a password
 */
UserSchema.methods.hashPassword = function(password) {
        if (this.salt && password) {
                return crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 10000,     64).toString('base64');
        } else {
                return password;
        }
};

/**
 * Create instance method for authenticating user
 */
UserSchema.methods.authenticate = function(password) {
        return this.password === this.hashPassword(password);
};

/**
 * Find possible not used username
 */
UserSchema.statics.findUniqueUsername = function(username, suffix, callback) {
        var _this = this;
        var possibleUsername = username + (suffix || '');

        _this.findOne({
                username: possibleUsername
        }, function(err, user) {
                if (!err) {
                        if (!user) {
                                callback(possibleUsername);
                        } else {
                                return _this.findUniqueUsername(username, (suffix || 0)     + 1, callback);
                        }
                } else {
                        callback(null);
                }
        });
};

mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Comment: In what file do you declare your mongoose scema and model? Can you post that code?

Comment: Right now it's very close to the boilerplate for the user model that mean.js sets up. It is declared in the user.server.model.js file. I'll append the question with the code.

Comment: Try exporting `mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);` and using that as your model.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand on that one, right now the last line of the user model file is exactly that line, and it should register it fine from there. I only get there error when I try to require this file from it's original location, but no errors when I require it from a copy in the same folder as the running app.

Comment: Try changing the last line to `module.exports=mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);` Then change `var User = mongoose.model('User');` to `var User = require('<path to your User file>');`. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: That works, and I suspected it would according to what I've read on the require function. The issue is that this breaks that express application that is loading it(mean.js based) due to it calling a naked require on each of the files in that directory, same as I was doing. But, it does work...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about express. I have done a few MEAN projects, and this hasn't been an issue.

Comment: Yeah, express may not be applicable as I'm using it here. I'm trying to figure out why this works with a local file, no changes, but using the file in another directory needs the above modifications, and if I can then use an unmodified file in some way(allowing the existing project to load the model file without modification).

Answer (score 0):

Change the last line to `module.exports=mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);`

Then change `var User = mongoose.model('User');` to `var User = require('<path to your User file>');`.

Comment: Upon further testing this does not work. I do get a User object, but it does not appear to have any access to the database. I can query the object in mongoose, but I get no valid responses. Again, when I include the same code from the local folder it works perfectly.

Comment: @Geek42 I am pretty sure this should work. Can you post a sample project?